# Makefile error on compiling C files

Tags: c, makefile

My directory structure is:

```
Project/
    + Source/
    |    + Module_1/
    |    |    + Module_1.c
    |    |    + Module_1.h
    |    |
    |    + Module_2/
    |    |    + Module_2.c
    |    |    + Module_2.h
    |    |
    |    + MainFile.c
    |    + MainFile.h
    |
    + Makefile
```

My `Makefile` contains:

```
SHELL     := /bin/sh
CC        := clang
AR        := ar
CFLAGS    := -fPIC -std=c99 -O2
LDFLAGS   := -shared
ARFLAGS   := -rcs

BLDDIR    := Build
OBJDIR    := Object

SOURCES   := $(wildcard Source/**/*.c Source/*.c)
OBJECTS   := $(patsubst %.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))

TARGET_A  := $(BLDDIR)/MyLibrary.a
TARGET_SO := $(patsubst %.a, %.so, $(TARGET_A))


PREFIX    ?= /usr/local


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.PHONY: all build clean dev distclean _dir

all: build

dev: CFLAGS := -g -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -std=c99
dev: all

build: _dir $(TARGET_A) $(TARGET_SO)
_dir:
    mkdir -p $(BLDDIR)
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(TARGET_A) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) %@ $(OBJECTS)
    $(AR) -s %@

$(TARGET_SO):
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


clean:
    $(RM) -r $(OBJDIR) test

distclean: clean
    $(RM) -r $(BLDDIR)
```

I have 1 question and 1 problem with this `Makefile`:

1. My problem is when I'm running this file I'm getting an error on line `$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c` and I don't know how to fix it? I tried to change it to `$(OBJECTS) : %.o : %.c` OR `%.o : %.c` and still no luck.
2. This is my first `Makefile` and I was wondering if my setup in this file looks OK or I need a better strategy/rules? If so how can I improve this?

---

**EDIT**

The error I'm getting is:

`make: *** No rule to make target 'Object/MainFile.c', needed by 'Object/MainFile.o'. Stop.`

---

**EDIT**

As @Beta point it out in the comment, I change the file name in each module so that `*.o` file name be different.

Comment: Are people still using makefiles? SCONS or Gradle?

Comment: That rule looks correct. What's the error?

Comment: Wild guess: Make sure you're prefixing your target commands with a single tab and not spaces.  Makefiles are weird like that.  And, post the error so we can help.

Comment: @Beta, I added the error message to the original port.

Comment: @RobJones, Indentation is correct, I think it got screwed up when I posted it. Also added error message to my original post.

Comment: @ManiH. It was a random guess.  Stupid question, `Object/MainFile.c` exists, right?

Comment: @RobJones, No problem. Yes all C and header files are exists. I'm thinking it might be the way that I'm creating `SOURCES` and `OBJECTS`.

Comment: There's a basic design problem here. Once this system is working, how many different `Module.o` files do you expect, and where do you want them?

Comment: @EdHeal I think [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) would be the choice here. Haven't used SCONS, but Gradle has its strength in Java world.

Comment: @yegorich - You can use Gradle for any project

Comment: @Beta You are right, I will be ended up to have only Module.o file since the file names are the same. Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile is trying to build a C-source file. You have a dependency of each object listed as `somefile.c`. Based on your make file it is up a directory and in the directory `Source`. So change the line `$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c` to `$(OBJDIR)/%.o : ../Source/%.c`. With that rule it should find the `.c` file and then execute the command, since the dependency of the `.o` file exists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your solution only works if all `%.c` files are in `Source` folder with no sub folder inside. My setup have 2 modules in different folder under `Source`.

Comment: What is the point of putting the object files in a location different from the source anyways? That is where the majority of your problems originate from. It's obviously not impossible, but there is no advantage to it.

Comment: Sorry didn't respond earlier, after I did some research base on your above comment, you are definitely right, there is no purpose / reason having separate `Object` folder, not even for `clean` operation. Thank you.